# Disable reboot through telnet alone

Tags: linux, telnet, reboot

I have a linux box, which can be accessed by minicom ports or telnet boxName method.
I need to disable reboot command through telnet session alone. Is it possible ?

eg:

```
]$ telnet linuxBox

In linuxBox Telnet

#
# reboot
reboot: Command not permitted in telnet
#
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say that but nobody uses "telnet" nowadays. Telnet is a security hole by itself. Why don't you use ssh?

But to answer your question, you can create a new user and use "sudo" grant to him to execute any required command but "reboot".

When sudo is configured on you server (man sudo, man sudoers) you can telnet (or ssh) your server, login as the above user.

Comment: Hi.. problem is that box does not have ssh support.. so I have to go with telnet.

Comment: Does your box have sudo? The proposed solution also works with telnet.

Comment: I will always login as root only